# Arangodb javascript cursors db._query()

Tags: arangodb, foxx, nosql

I'm using arangodb cursor through javascript client

`db._query('query', {param: value})`

My query contains limit operator and I need a total count. How can I pass `fullCount` option into cursor and read `extra.fullCount` back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running the query from the ArangoShell, then the easiest should be setting the `options` attribute when calling `db._query()` like this:

```
var data = { 
  query: "FOR doc IN collection FILTER doc.attr == @value LIMIT 0, 5 RETURN doc", 
  bindVars: { value: "foo" }, 
  options: { fullCount: true } 
};

var result = db._query(data);
full = result.getExtra().stats.fullCount;
```

The `options` object is optional. If it contains a `fullCount` subattribute, the query result will contain a `fullCount` subattribute in its statistics. In the above example, the result is captured in variable `full`.